# Variable to get data from API using AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to output a list of field names with an AJAX call. It needs to look like this `var test = ['test1', 'test2', etc.]`

**JQuery:**

```
var test = [
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/api/artikel/list',
      success: function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, artikel) {
          var name = artikel.naam;
          var list = [];
          console.log(list);
        });
      }
    })
]
```

The output is showing me the field values separately and each in their own list. How do I get the values into 1 list?

I can't figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to do?

You have to initialize a list and then append each data value on success callback

```
var test = [];

$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/api/artikel/list',
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(i, artikel) {
      var name = artikel.naam;
      test.push(name)
    });
  }
})
```

If not please provide more context to your problem.

Comment: Thanks!! I needed to put the list outside of the AJAX call. Works great right now!